# Java: Sorting specific Strings first, then sort by alpha numeric

Tags: java, sorting

I try to sort according to:

MyPOJO:

```
String city;
String tokenA;
String tokenB;
```

city is a name of a City.

tokenA can only be either "ALARM" or "ALERT"

tokenB can only be either "ALARM" or "ALERT"

- MyPOJO with "ALARM" in either tokenA or tokenB or both must come first
- MyPOJO with "ALERT" in either tokenA or tokenB or both must come second
- last all the cities should come, sorted alphanumeric

If several MyPOJO's has "ALARM" in both tokenA and tokenB, sort according to city within.

If several MyPOJO's has "ALERT" in both tokenA and tokenB, sort according to city within.

A MyPOJO with ALARM in any field or both fields must always come before ALERT.

I have the first tokenA but Im not sure how to best bring in tokenB.

Code I have:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object other) {
    if (other == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    MyPOJO that = (MyPOJO) other;

    int token = tokenA.compareTo(that.tokenA);
    if (token != 0) {
        return token;
    }

    return city.compareTo(that.city);
}
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?  Your posted code looks like a template where the part you are to fill in hasn't been touched.

Comment: My question is how I can add code to sort ALARM and ALERT first, city is already ordered. If you have any valuable feedback please help.

Comment: Unrelated: if your tokens are restricted in their values - why aren't you using enums then?

Comment: Enums is also good, but my problem is more related to solving the algorithm and the sorting.

Comment: So if a MyPOJO has ALARM in tokenA, it should go first (rule 1), and has ALERT in tokenB it should go second (rule 2)?

Comment: If one POJO has ALARM in either or both it should always come before ALERT. If more POJO's has ALARM in both tokenA and tokenB, then sort by City. After ALARM comes always ALERT. Its ALERT if there is no ALARM in tokenA or tokenB. If more POJO's has ALERT in both tokenA and tokenB, then sort by City. At the end if no ALARM or ALERT sort only by City.

Comment: For those who down voted my question, please come forward and tell me why in comment below. I'd like to improve the question, or maybe you can even give me another answer how to solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the method you want.
In the `compareTo` method do this:

```
if tokenA == ALARM and other.tokenA != ALARM return -1
if tokenA != ALARM and other.tokenA == ALARM return 1
if tokenB == ALARM and other.tokenB != ALARM return -1
if tokenB != ALARM and other.tokenB == ALARM return 1
if tokenB == ALARM and other.tokenB == ALARM
  return city.compareTo(other.city)
if tokenA == ALERT and other.tokenA != ALERT return -1
if tokenA != ALERT and other.tokenA == ALERT return 1
if tokenB == ALERT and other.tokenB != ALERT return -1
if tokenB != ALERT and other.tokenB == ALERT return 1
if tokenB == ALERT and other.tokenB == ALERT 
  return city.compareTo(other.city)
return city.compareTo(other.city)
```

Comment: Thanks!, but when two POJO has all fields set to ALARM, it does not sort according to city. See if I can figure it out...

Comment: Its OK. But I needed to add return city.compareTo(other.city) in step 5. and in step 10, plus last step 11.

Comment: I detected one thing if tokenA=ALERT and tokenB=ALARM, this POJO should come after any POJO with tokenA="" and tokenB=ALARM. I.e. Any ALARM should always come before any ALERT, no ALARM or ALERT then sort alpha numeric. Looks like "" should be ignored unless both tokenA and tokenB are "", then sort alpha numeric